# img onError event returns linting warning 'Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners'

Tags: reactjs, lint, onerror

I keep the receiving an linting warning when using the 'onerror' event on img. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Error: Non-interactive elements should not be assigned mouse or keyboard event listeners

jsx:

```
const handlerErrorNoImage = (event) => {
    event.target.src = blankProfile
  }

<img src="./myimage" onError={handlerErrorNoImage} alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't researched why `onError` is interpreted as a mouse or keyboard event. However, below at least removes the warning:

`// eslint-disable
<img src="./myimage" onError={handlerErrorNoImage} alt="" />
// eslint-enable`